# Detectar cuando el usuario presione el botón Retroceso en un Edittext (Android)

Tags: java, android, edittext

Quiero saber como detectar cuando el usuario presione el botón retroceso del teclado en un **EditText** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado usando esta función pero no me ha funcionado.

```
etText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        Log.i("Tecla", "...");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Esto solo es posible en teclados físicos. Si lo que quieres es crear una lógica al eliminar un caracter, debes definir un algoritmo utilizando [TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543479/5280677) en el `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Debes implementar una clase que extienda de EditText para tener tu keyboard personalizado, y después usar esta en lugar del EditText nativo de Android:

```
public class ZanyEditText extends EditText {

private Random r = new Random();

public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ZanyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ZanyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setRandomBackgroundColor() {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r
            .nextInt(256)));
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
            true);
}

private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            ZanyEditText.this.setRandomBackgroundColor();
            // Un-comment if you wish to cancel the backspace:
            // return false;
        }
        return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
    }

}
```

}